# (quasi-)coherent sheaves with finite support/finite length

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

I have some trouble visualizing (quasi-)coherent sheaves with finite support (for example a point) or even finite length.

Algebraically, in the affine case over $\text{Spec} A$, one point support should correspond to modules over $A$ whose localization at every prime but some $\mathfrak p$ is zero. What do such $A$-modules look like? Would the additional requirement length 1 imply that <s>the module localized at $\mathfrak p$ is equal to $A_{\mathfrak p}$</s>? **Edit: thanks Pavel**.

The question arose when coming across various instances where sheaf quotients are taken, for example considering *a maximal flag of coherent sub-$\mathcal O_{\overline X}$ given by $\mathcal F=\mathcal F_0\supset\mathcal F_{-1}\supset\cdots\supset\mathcal F_{-t}=\mathcal F(-P)$ such that length$(\mathcal F_{k+1}/\mathcal F_k)=1$*, where $P$ is a certain closed point, $\overline X$ a reduced, irreducible complete curve, $\mathcal F$ a torsion-free coherent $\mathcal O_{\overline X}$-Module. (I can provide more context if needed). Essentially I am asking: **what is/how to think about $\mathcal F_{k+1}/\mathcal F_k$?** If I understand correctly, length 1 is a stronger property than being supported at a point.

Another related example would be Drinfeld's shtukas, where we also have cokernels with "small" support.

An answer that illuminates the geometric point of view (for example on a curve, via sections/functions on the curve etc) and some of the algebra (affine case?) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If your ring $A$ is Noetherian, then for a finitely generated module $M$, one has $\mathrm{Supp}\;M=V(\mathrm{Ann}\;M)$, so the modules you describe are precisely the (finite length if you like) modules with $\sqrt{\mathrm{Ann}\;M}$ being a maximal ideal. Some cyclic examples (not exhaustive) are $A/\mathfrak{m}^n$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal. If the length of the module is $1$, then the module is simple, so the annihilator is exactly the maximal ideal. That is, the module is the residue field $\kappa(\mathfrak{m})=A/\mathfrak{m},$ not $A_\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: Ah I feel stupid. Of course it's $\kappa(\mathfrak{m})=A/\mathfrak{m}$ not $A_{\mathfrak m}$. So a length 1 sheaf of modules is, in a sense, a ''smallest'' possible sheaf of modules, given by a residue field as an $A$-module.